# Network Has Slow Performance in SDE

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, performance, network

I am working with ArcGIS Network Analyst (10.5.1).  I created a network in SDE and everything worked fine.  The network is versioned on SDE.

I updated the source line features of the network in a geodatabase on my local drive by adding new line segments, rebuilt, tested it, and it still performs as expected.

I then used Delete Rows and Append tools to load the updated line features into the network on SDE and rebuilt it.  Routing and other analysis still work, but now the performance is much slower.  A routing analysis that used to take a couple seconds to solve now takes close to a minute.

Has anyone else experienced this? Anyone have any thoughts what can be done to optimize or speed up a network stored in SDE?

I suspect if I delete and recreate the network in SDE it would work OK again, but I would like to avoid going through that whole process every time I need to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely occurring since the feature classes are registered as versioned.  When you performed the Delete Rows and Append, it will add all those records to the A & D tables (delta tables) that are created when you version a feature class.  The delta tables are queried when using the data.

You can perform a compress of the geodatabase to clear the A & D tables, but you will want to make sure there are no locks.  Or, you could unversion the feature classes and choose the option to compress the edits, and then re-register the feature classes as versioned.